# Combining Option Boxes and Combo Boxes to Add Records to the right table

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, combobox, vba

thanks for all the communal help thus far! Referencing this site is a beautiful thing.

I've designed a front-end in Access and am having trouble getting my VBA code to work... would very much appreciate any feedback or suggestions! I'm still pretty new to VB and could very well be missing some basic components for this use-case....

Essentially my db is made up of 8 tables and then the relationship tables that join them. I want to build in the functionality that allows users to "attach" or relate entities in one table to others from a form.

Option buttons point to the different entity tables and set the record source for the combo box to choose any given record.

THE PROBLEM: my issue is trying to CREATE NEW record using all the info that users provide/choose(w/the comboboxes)

The Debugger has identified this line to be an issue:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(BUS_APP_SERVER_REL)
```

.. but my full code is below:

```
Private Sub Check259_Click()

Dim BP4_BizApp As String
BP4_BizApp = "SELECT [BUS_APPL_NAME],[BUS_APPL_ID] FROM [BUSINESS_APPLICATIONS] ORDER BY [BUS_APPL_NAME]"

If Me.Check259 = True Then
     Me.Combo257.RowSource = BP4_BizApp
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Check261_Click()
Dim BP4_ITApp As String
BP4_ITApp = "SELECT [IT_APPL_NAME],[IT_APPL_ID] FROM [IT_APPLICATIONS] ORDER BY [IT_APPL_NAME]"
 If Me.Check261 = -1 Then
         Me.Combo257.RowSource = BP4_ITApp
         End If
End Sub
Private Sub Check263_Click()
Dim BP4_Tool As String
BP4_Tool = "SELECT [TOOL_NAME],[TOOL_ID] FROM [TOOLS] ORDER BY [TOOL_NAME]"
       If Me.Check263 = -1 Then
             Me.Combo257.RowSource = BP4_Tool
             End If
End Sub
Private Sub Check_265_Click()
Dim BP4_DB As String
BP4_DB = "SELECT [DB_NAME],[DB_ID] FROM [Databases] ORDER BY [DB_NAME]"
    If Me.Check265 = -1 Then
                Me.Combo257.RowSource = BP4_DB
                End If
End Sub


Private Sub Command221_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim SVR_ID As Variant
  Dim BizApp_ID  As Variant
  Dim ENV As Variant
  Dim COMM As String

BizApp_ID = Me.Combo257.AfterUpdate
SVR_ID = Me!SERVER_ID
ENV = Me.Combo214.AfterUpdate
COMM = Me!Text216

  Set dbVideoCollection = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(BUS_APP_SERVER_REL)

  rs.AddNew
  rs(BUS_APPL_ID).Value = BizApp_ID
  rs("SERVER_ID").Value = SVR_ID
  rs("ENV_TYPE").Value = ENV
  rs("COMMENTS").Value = COMM
  rs.Update
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time!
Ryan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ryan.  What is `BUS_APP_SERVER_REL`?  If that is the name of a table or saved query, put quotes around it: `db.OpenRecordset("BUS_APP_SERVER_REL")`  If instead it is the name of a string variable, what is its value?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things here.  Let's look at this sub:

```
Private Sub Command221_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim SVR_ID As Variant
  Dim BizApp_ID  As Variant
  Dim ENV As Variant
  Dim COMM As String

BizApp_ID = Me.Combo257.AfterUpdate
SVR_ID = Me!SERVER_ID
ENV = Me.Combo214.AfterUpdate
COMM = Me!Text216

  Set dbVideoCollection = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(BUS_APP_SERVER_REL)

  rs.AddNew
  rs(BUS_APPL_ID).Value = BizApp_ID
  rs("SERVER_ID").Value = SVR_ID
  rs("ENV_TYPE").Value = ENV
  rs("COMMENTS").Value = COMM
  rs.Update
End Sub
```

First of all, you're Dimming db as Database.  Then you're setting dbVideoCollection = CurrentDb.  Then you're using db.OpenRecordset.  I think you want to change "dbVideoCollection" to just "db".

Then, as HansUp noticed, you've got BUS_APP_SERVER_REL.  If that's a table name or a query name, it's got to be in quotes.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("BUS_APP_SERVER_REL")
```

If it's a variable name, it's got to be wrapped in quotes (I believe):

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("" & BUS_APP_SERVER_REL & "")
```

Comment: You're right, JB, there are multiple issues.  What do you think about `BizApp_ID = Me.Combo257.AfterUpdate`?

Comment: I've never heard of a variable being set equal to an event, I just figured it might be something I've never used.

Comment: You can use `Me.myControl.AfterUpdate` (it's a property of the control), but usually it will simply give `[Event Procedure]` or a function name. Most certainly not what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Some more things...

1) I suggest to add [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to the top of your module, it enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared variables/constants already at compile time.

This would have prevented the `db` vs. `dbVideoCollection` mix-up.

To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

2) Please don't use the default control names like `Check263` or `Command221`, especially when they will be used in the code (but you should make it a general habit). Use meaningful names that you will recognize.

Some months from now you will look at your code, scratching your head *"what was this line supposed to do... wait, which one was Check261 again?"*.

3) `BizApp_ID = Me.Combo257.AfterUpdate` makes no sense, you probably want simply
`BizApp_ID = Me.Combo257.Value`.